# Allow user to click on a button and in this case countdown timer must NOT be interrupted/refreshed

Tags: php, mysql, timer

I have following problem:
There is a site based on php+MySQL. On particular page there is:
- a countdown timer which is redirecting user automatically in 10 seconds to another page

```
header("Refresh: 10; URL=http://localhost:81/redirect.php?user_id=" . $user_id);
```

-a button on a form which is updating table.

```
if(isset($_POST['button_1')){
$u = "UPDATE users SET name = 'Name' WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$ru = mysqli_query ($dbc, $u) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));}
```

As soon as user click on button within 10 seconds - counter starts from the beggining because POST method is somehow refreshing it.

My aim is to allow user to click on a button and in this case countdown timer must NOT be interupted/refreshed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this piece of code before doing ANY output to the client, otherwise the else condition will FAIL

```
if(isset($_POST['button_1')){
   $u = "UPDATE users SET name = 'Name' WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
   $ru = mysqli_query ($dbc, $u) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " .     mysqli_error($dbc));}
else{
   header("Refresh: 10; URL=http://localhost:81/redirect.php?user_id=" . $user_id);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I still can interuped countdown upon button is clicked.